# cant resize image to 72 x 72 in cs5

Tags: resize, photoshop, flash-cs5

I'm trying to make a 72 x 72 high resolution icon for my Hello World (Android) app.

I went to Image Resize, typed 72 in height and width automatically changed to 59.  I changed width to 72 and the height changed to 88.  I can't get them both to change to 72 - is this possible to do?

http://i1043.photobucket.com/albums/b439/darrengove/resize.png

Comment: If the image isn't square to start with, resize won't make it square unless you click the link icon to unlock the aspect ratio.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Thanks a lot Dave!!! Sorry for a bit of a noobish question.

Comment: This should be moved to http://superuser.com/.  This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can first resize it to 88x72 px, and after that crop it with Crop tool (Ctrl+Alt+C).

That's it :)